# VB.NET ~ Sub Routines - can they be saved to a text file and then called?

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have about 100 sub routines that I need to use..I am going to be calling them into a web browser component do get some elements after each web page has completed.

Is it possible to create one sub routine and then has say a streamreader loop through a folder and read each text file in the folder to put the sub into a string?

I would then simply call that one sub into the webbrowser component but I didn't know if this was possible?

There would be about 100 different text files in the folder.

The thinking behind this would be that if I wanted to add more website instructions to the sub or take away from the sub I could just delete a text file.

How would one begin this crazy journey?

Thanks

Comment: "How would one begin this crazy journey?" - with the word 'Stop!' !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't really something you would want to do.  Its also not possible since vb.net is a compiled language it can't just read the text of the code on the fly and implement it like that.

You are better off investigating another pattern that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can programmatically create a vb.net program on the fly. I created a web program which rewrites itself as I see fit. Part of that code adds new subroutines to the same vb.net program. Basically writing more sub routines to itself and then it runs itself again. You can easily store your other subs into txt files and then recall the data later if you wanted. The trick here, however, is that you have to first add the sub routines into an entirely new file, then, when all the writing is done, you can then preform the following:

```
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("your old file name"))
File.Copy(Server.MapPath("your new file name"), Server.MapPath("your old file name"))
```

It should be noted that I make web applications, so it doesn't quite work the same. Using asp.net pages, the way I get the new program to run with the new sub routines is to run on the client side code, in which I include a little timed refresh, which fires once the rewriting task is finished. The page then refreshes with the new vb.net back end code in place.

In order to do this for a desktop application or whatever might require something else which I am not aware of.